# How to inline text and image

Tags: svg, button, padding, inline

I have an rectangle, I am trying to put a text and an small image sit in the middle of it ( image and text are inline ). The image and the  text must to  have a fixed gap so when I change the length of the  text, the image still away from the text with a fixed gap.

And I am also trying to put a function to the image ( If i clicked it, a link to an website`d appeared )

This is what i`m trying to replicate

[An example in image for what  I am saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ9iz.png)

This is my code so far ( i`ve tried some methods but they did not work )

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 500)
                                     .attr("height", 500);
 
var g = d3.select("svg") .append("g")
 var rectangle = g.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("width", 300)
                  .attr("height", 200)
                  .style("fill","pink");
                         
 var text = g.append("text")
 .attr("x",150)
 .attr("y",100)
 .attr("text-anchor","middle")
 .text('Nam oc cho')
 
 var img = g.append("image")
 .attr("x",200)
 .attr("y",85)
 .attr("href","firefox.jpg")
 .attr("height","20px")
.attr("width","20px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/namkhoai16/o7cm9n35/38/

Comment: Why is there not an image? SVG does not do reflows so without javascript you won't get an image to move when text length changes.

Comment: I am trying to do it with  d3.js but i don`t know exactly how to make it reflow

Comment: i`ve just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Since the text is written with text-anchor: middle it has half its length before 150 and half after. So we just need to add half its length to its x position to find its end.

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 500)
                                     .attr("height", 500);
 
var g = d3.select("svg") .append("g")
 var rectangle = g.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("width", 300)
                  .attr("height", 200)
                  .style("fill","pink");
                         
 var text = g.append("text")
 .attr("x",150)
 .attr("y",100)
 .attr("text-anchor","middle")
 .text('Nam oc cho')
 
 var img = g.append("image")
 .attr("x",150 + text.node().getComputedTextLength () / 2)
 .attr("y",85)
 .attr("href","https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/0ssO7VfSYSEzbQVQ6uK6FYamQx4=/940x0/2014/06/13/c582d2aa-092e-4d29-a616-a1e5c9403b36/firefox-logo-2014-vertical-4sts.jpg")
 .attr("height","20px")
.attr("width","20px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help, you are the best